# Error icon when first run terminal (using oh-my-zsh) on Mac

Tags: macos, terminal, oh-my-zsh

I always got an error when start terminal. It doesn't show error message, only show icon only. I see the `/var/log/system.log` there is no message too.
[Here is screenshot when start terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jjsp1.png)

How to see error log? or anybody know why this error come?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is only a display error. It depends on how your theme determines the exit status of the previous command.

For example, if it uses the parameter `pipestatus` it might lead to this problem.
`pipestatus` is undefined immediately after the shell starts and will only be set once a command has been run. Should the theme only check for the exit code `0` in order to display a symbol for success, this check might fail on an undefined/empty `pipestatus`.

The error code of the last command is also stored in the parameter `?` (or `status`). Unlike `pipestatus` `?` is already defined at the shell status. Run

```
echo $?
```

as the first command after you start a terminal. If it returns `0`, it would indicate that there was indeed no error.

Without knowing which theme you use it is hard to tell for sure.

---

Should there indeed be an error somewhere, it would not show in `/var/log/system.log`. Only system services will report errors in this file.

Answer (score 0):

It's a macOS Mojave error. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/110501. If you run `cat /var/log/system.log` It will show you:

```
iTerm2[28086]: DEPRECATED USE in libdispatch client: dispatch source activated with no event handler set; set a breakpoint on _dispatch_bug_deprecated to debug
```

Reinstall oh-my-zsh would fix this (which means a lot of work to do). https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh

But I think it's not a big deal, I prefer to wait for Apple fix it.